# I want to write a regex for the format: {Ex:bin 1/2=2GHz/1.8GHz}

Tags: javascript

I'm new to this and want to write a regex for the format:

```
{Ex:bin 1/2=2GHz/1.8GHz}
```

Please check regex as it isn't working:

```
^([A-Za-z]{3}[]\d+/\d+=\d+(\.\d{2})?[A-Za-z]+\s?/\d+(\.\d{2})?[A-Za-z]+\s?,)+$
```

Comment: well I don't see any : for starters.  I'm confused as to how that regex is supposed to match up with that format.  What are the [] for, for example?  Maybe you could be more specific on what you are trying to do?

Comment: what do you want to be matched exactly

Comment: Please can you give a better idea of the possible alterations in accepted strings?

Comment: The input entered should be in the format " bin 1/2=2GHz/1.8GHz".

Comment: The input entered should be in the format " bin 1/2=2GHz/1.8GHz".
I want to write a regex to match the above format.
The [] is to allow a blank space after 'bin'.
Also, the regex should allow the pattern to repeat, i.e "bin 1/2=2GHz/1.8GHz , bin 4/5=40GHz/48GHz". I want it to be separated by a comma.....Plz suggest changes or a new regex to match this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest coming up with several examples of strings to be matched or not matched, then breaking them into pieces and testing the pieces individually with a tool like this:

http://regexpal.com/